# Graphing Derivatives of Parametric Equations

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, parametric

I'm trying to graph the second derivative of a parametric equation. For some reason I can't get my second derivative tangent line to track the slope of the first derivative curve:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xggvilrmul

My tangent line for the first derivative is perfect, I'm missing something with the second derivative. The math for both derivatives where taken from:

http://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Certificate%20Level/Parametric%20differentiation.htm

I couldn't find any error with the calculations above, so I'm at a loss as to exactly where the breakdown is occurring.

Thanks!

Comment: The derivative of $(t+\cos(t),\sin(t))$ should be $(1-\sin(t),\cos(t))$.

Comment: Parametric derivatives are not evaluated in isolation. The page I linked to above gives a good primer for the process.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand at all what you mean by "Parametric derivatives are not evaluated in isolation". The derivative of $(x(t),y(t))$ should be $(x'(t),y'(t))$, there is no other definition.

Comment: All right, I just understood. You should have not called the first parameter $t$ but $x$, and the second is $y=f'(x)$ because the abscissa has no longer the meaning of "t'. This may explain the issue you have later.